# Beginner looking for guidance

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm programming a very basic menu calculator that

1. displays a menu
2. gets the users choice and performs an action based on that choice
3. display the results
4. loop back to the menu until the user enters 10 to exit the loop

What has confused me is using a switch statement in a while loop. Entering 10 is supposed to exit the program and it does, but only at first. The second time it shows the menu and asks for input, 10 does not exit the program.

any other advice is also very welcomed

```
    public class MenuCalculator 
    {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        showMenu();
    }

    public static void showMenu() 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //menu display   
        System.out.println("Calculator Menu");
        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.println("1. Add two integers. ");
        System.out.println("2. Add two doubles. ");
        System.out.println("3. Subtract two integers. ");
        System.out.println("4. Subtract two doubles. ");
        System.out.println("5. Multiply two integers. ");
        System.out.println("6. Multiply two doubles. ");
        System.out.println("7. Divide two integers. ");
        System.out.println("8. Divide two douvles. ");
        System.out.println("9. Compute a factorial product of a number (n!) ");
        System.out.println("10. Exit. ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Your choice?");
        int userChoice = input.nextInt();

        while (userChoice < 10) 
        {

            switch (userChoice) 
            {

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter the first number * : ");
                    int addInt1 = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter the 2nd number: ");
                    int addInt2 = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(add(addInt1, addInt2));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Enter the first number !: ");
                    double plusDub1 = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter the 2nd number:  @");
                    double plusDub2 = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println(addDbl(plusDub1, plusDub2));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Enter the first number: #");
                    int subInt1 = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter the 2nd number: ");
                    int subInt2 = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(subtract(subInt1, subInt2));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Enter the first number: $");
                    double subDub1 = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter the 2nd number: ");
                    double subDub2 = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println(subtractDbl(subDub1, subDub2));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Enter the first number: %");
                    int multInt1 = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter the 2nd number: ");
                    int multInt2 = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(multiply(multInt1, multInt2));
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Enter the first number: ^");
                    double multDub1 = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter the 2nd number: ");
                    double multDub2 = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println(multiplyDbl(multDub1, multDub2));
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("Enter the first number: &");
                    int divInt1= input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter the 2nd number: ");
                    int divInt2= input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(divide(divInt1, divInt2));
                    break;
                case 8:
                    System.out.println("Enter the first number: -");
                    double divDub1= input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter the 2nd number: ");
                    double divDub2= input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println(divideDbl(divDub1, divDub2));
                    break;
                case 9:
                    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
                    int factoNum= input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(factorialProduct(factoNum));
                    break;
                default:

            }//end switch
            showMenu();
        }//end while


    }

    public static int add(int n1, int n2) 
    {
        //declare variables       
        int sum;
        // sum and return        
        sum = n1 + n2;
        return sum;

     }

    public static double addDbl(double n1, double n2) 
    {
        //declaration
        double sum;
        // sum and return        
        sum = n1 + n2;
        return sum;

    }

    public static int subtract(int n1, int n2) 
    {
        int total;
        total = n1 - n2;
        return total;
    }

    public static double subtractDbl(double n1, double n2) 
    {
        double total;
        total = n1 - n2;
        return total;
    }

    public static int multiply(int n1, int n2) 
    {
        int total;
        total = n1 * n2;
        return total;
    }

    public static double multiplyDbl(double n1, double n2) 
    {
        double total;
        total = n1 * n2;
        return total;
    }

    public static int divide(int n1, int n2) 
    {
        int total;
        total = n1 / n2;
        return total;
    }

    public static double divideDbl(double n1, double n2) 
    {
        double total;
        total = n1 / n2;
        return total;
    }

    public static int factorialProduct(int n) 
    {
        if (n == 0) 
        {
            return 1;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return n * factorialProduct(n - 1);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: First guidance: improve your question. 1. The title should summarize your question, not your plight. 2. You need to ask a single and specific question, tell the details, describe the code, not a multi-part question. 3. .You will want to through the [ask] and the [help] to see how this site works and how to improve your question.

Comment: Note also that this is a specific Question/Answer site, not a mentoring, guidance or tutoring site.

Comment: Oh my, your code is recursive where the showMenu method is calling itself and you *really* ***really*** don't want to be doing this. First thing I would do would be to get rid of the recursion and use a more simple and cleaner while loop, get the input using the Scanner ***within*** that while loop.

Comment: Code alignments. Question grammatical improvements. Text format displaying.

Comment: i appreciate that. and apologies for the post as this is my first one and should've done more research on this site before posting. Since all the tutoring labs have been shut down I've been scrambling for help

Answer (score 0):

You call `showMenu` from `showMenu`, which is recursion, and you definitely don't need this here. What you need instead is a while loop around getting the mode and executing the operation. I would shape the code like this (warning - pseudocode):

```
public static void main() {
  while (true) {
    // display your menu
    userChoice = nextInt()
    switch (userChoice) {
      case 1:
        ...
      case 2:
        ...
      ...
      case 10:
        return;  // exits from main
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Much more simple than what i was doing. Thanks!

Comment: @Romero12 If this solves your problem then please upvote/accept my answer.